# Oddity with System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories

Tags: .net, filesystems, directory-structure

Just something I noticed today when doing directory searches that might trip some people up.

I found on my Windows XP machine that

System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories("C:\")  gave me 17 folders

System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories("C:")  gave me 17 folders

System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories("D:\")  gave me 12 folders

**System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories("D:")  gave me 0 folders**

I was trying to figure out why my search was missing my D drive.

Comment: Well, it comes down to figuring out what  Directory.InternalGetFileDirectoryNames(string path, string userPathOriginal, string searchPattern, bool includeFiles, bool includeDirs, SearchOption searchOption)  does.  But I would guess that current directory is possibly right.  The app I was debugging was in a leaf folder on the D drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that `GetDirectories("D:")` gives you the list of directories within the *current directory* of your D drive, while `GetDirectories("D:\")` gives you the list of directories in the *root* of your D drive.

If your D drive's root has 12 directories and the current directory is on your D drive and has no directories in it, those are the results you should expect.

Comment: Windows doesn't actually have a concept of a current directory per drive. It's simulated by cmd.exe for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

Windows has historically provided backwards compatibility with DOS which treated paths that contained only a drive letter without a directory as a reference to the drive's "current directory". But since there isn't actually a current directory per drive (cmd.exe simulates this, according to [Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/10/11/10073890.aspx)) my guess is that it's returning nothing because the current directory for the process is on the C: drive. Try setting Environment.CurrentDirectory to D:\ then see if you get the same results.

Comment: Good explaination.  And it fits.  But Ooh if only there was con sistency between shares and local disk handling.

Answer (score 0):

What is the current directory of drive D:?

It's not the root.